# Django truncatewords filter tag with an href link for the ellipsis

Tags: python, django, django-template-filters

I want to truncate my post content using a Django template tag filter such as (|truncatewords_html: my_number). But with an href link for the ellipsis that redirect the user to the detailed post full content.

Beside defining a custom template tag filter (as quoted in similar but quite older threads), I want to know if there is a built-in method to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. Instead of building the logic in the template tag filter of Django, I send my JSON API data (Built with Django Rest Framework) to be consumed by my front end (where I am using the JQuery library).  The code is as the following:

Serializers.py:

```
class PostListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
   url = post_detail_url
   username = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   date_created = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   def get_username(self, obj):
      return obj.user.username

   def get_date_created(self, obj):
      return obj.created.strftime('%b %d %Y | at %I:%M %p')

   class Meta:
      model = Post
      fields = [
          'id',
          'username',
          'title',
          'slug',
          'content',
          'url',
          'date_created',
          ]
```

views.py:

```
class PostListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.PostListSerializer
```

and finally my post_list.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/posts/',
      method: 'GET',
      success: function(data){
        // iterate through the array of objects
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
          var postUser= value.username;
          var postTitle = value.title;
          var postSlug = value.slug;
          var postCreated = value.date_created;
          var postContent = value.content;
          var postShort;

          if (postContent.length >= 50){
            // truncate long posts
            postShort = jQuery.trim(postContent).substring(0, 50).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ")
        + "<a href='/posts/" + postSlug + "'>" + "..." + "</a>";
          } else {
            postShort = postContent;
          }

          $('#posts-container').append(
            "<div>" + "<h4>" + postUser + ": " + "<a href='/posts/"
        + postSlug + "'>" + postTitle + "</a>" + "<h5>"
        + postCreated + "</h5>" + postShort + "</div>" + "<hr>"
          );
        });
      },
      error: function(data){
        console.log('error');
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```